# How to align item to the very bottom within flexible box layout column?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So far I have the three columns laid out in a vertical box (can't post images yet so here's a link):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdDyK.jpg

```
<div id="vbox">
<div id="blck1"></div>
<div id="blck2"></div>
<div id="blck3"><div id="yellow"></div><div id="blue"></div></div>
</div>
```

css

```
 #vbox{
 display: box;
 box-orient: vertical;
 }
 #vbox > div {
 box-flex: 1;
 }
```

The problem is that I don't know how to get the blue box to align to the bottom of the third column.. I tried all the alignment properties, i must be doing something wrong.
Any ideas???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost, you should use the new CSS Flexible Box Module syntax (which is now referred to as "Flex" rather than "Box"). See the spec here: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/

Here is an example of what you are trying to accomplish (in Chrome/Safari): http://jsfiddle.net/PU2AV/

On your third `<div>` I've set:

```
-webkit-justify-content: space-between;
```

This creates the space in-between the two elements (if you added more, it would evenly divide the space between all of them).

Alternatively, you could add a third `<div>` between #yellow and #blue and give it:

```
-webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
```

This would cause it to "flex" between #yellow and #blue (which have static heights), pushing #blue all the way down. If you left it with a transparent background, it would have the same effect. Sometimes you may find it useful to have the flexible space as an actual element.

Comment: I just realized that this doesn't look as expected in Safari...is it fully supported yet?

Comment: Hmmm, looks like Safari isn't using a recent WebKit build or has decided to ignore the newer `flex` properties for now. I made a version that uses `box` here: http://jsfiddle.net/PU2AV/1/. That will work fine in Safari and Chrome still supports that syntax as well.

Nothing in HTML5/CSS3 is considered "fully supported" though since none of it is standardized yet... there are just working drafts. It could all change at any time.

Comment: ugh..just realized neither work in firefox! firefox is so behind... any possible work arounds?

Comment: Well in these examples only -webkit- properties were used. Even so, none of the other browsers respect box-align:justify, so you'll have to use a filler element between the yellow and blue blocks. Here's a version that should work in most browsers: http://jsfiddle.net/PU2AV/3/ Remember that this is all done with the old specification and it is being replaced by the new flexible box model.